# Breakpoint highlight changing in VS2015 Pro

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro with an MVC project.  Normally, setting a breakpoint on a C# line highlights it with the default white-on-maroon color which is fine.  However sometimes I notice that the highlight color for that breakpoint is different.  Exiting VS, then entering and reloading my project usually fixes the problem.

After digging into the Fonts and Colors settings, I've discovered that the breakpoint color is changing to the Code Coverage (partial) color.  If I change that color in the settings, the breakpoint color changes with it.

I would gladly turn off Code Coverage, or even clear the results, but everything I've searched for describes doing things to windows and options that I just don't seem to have.  From what I've read, it appears that Code Coverage is something you get with the Enterprise version of VS, but it doesn't make sense that you'd have the settings to change code coverage colors on lesser versions of VS.

It's driving me crazy.  I've used Visual Studio since before it had a year attached to its name, but this one has me stumped.

So far everything I've found mentions doing things to the Code Coverage Result window, but I can't *find* a Code Coverage Result window.

I've also looked into IntelliTest, but that seems to only be an Enterprise feature.

Finally, others have mentioned looking for .runsettings and .testsettings files and removing them, but they don't exist.

Has anyone else had this issue, or more importantly, does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this.  I could just change the various Code Coverage colors to match the breakpoint highlight color, but I'd really rather not.

Comment: Did you try  `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`K`, `H` ?

Comment: I don't have any breakpoint highlight in the C# code at all! I thought this is a change in the VS 2015, but seems like it's a bug.